# How to open URL through the button?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I have a `UITextView` where I type some text. I have a `UIButton`. I want to click the button and open URL where the text I've typed in the `UITextView` should appear. I am writing a dictionary app for IOS 7, and this function is needed when I want to ask people to translate my text. I know how to open just URL, but my text should appear in the box that is in URL. Can somebody help me with coding?

```
SozdikViewController.h
@interface SozdikViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *Button_Ask;
-(IBAction)ask;
@end
```

And this is my SozdikViewController.m file

```
#import "SozdikViewController.h"
@interface SozdikViewController ()
@end
@implementation SozdikViewController
-(IBAction)ask
{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.audaru.kz/?product=SoylemMT&word="]];
}
...

@end
```

Comment: NSString *url = self.textView1.text;

Answer (score 1):

```
-(IBAction)ask
{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.audaru.kz/?product=SoylemMT&word=%@",textView1.text]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want to translate the text which had been typed in UITextField. So you have to simple use

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.audaru.kz/?product=SoylemMT&word=%@", textView1.text]]];
```

And move `%@`in correct position in your url.
Hope it helps

Comment: I would highly advise against doing all that in a single line. You should first get the text, convert it to an URL then open it. You code is quite hard to read if you write it as it is.

Comment: @LordZsolt I tried to make a code like an author's question.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Though if his coding style is a little weird, you shouldn't advise him to continue using that coding style, it'll be harder for him to switch later on when a PM/Boss tells him to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
//Append your word in the text field to the url

 NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.audaru.kz/?product=SoylemMT&word=%@",textField.text];            
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the URL from the text view with:

```
NSString *urlString = self.textView.text;
```

Then you can open the url with:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have included comments in my code to explain each step but you should just be able to construct an `NSString *` using `stringWithFormat:` and pass it your URL of (`http://www.audaru.kz/?product=SoylemMT&word=%@`) and the value that `[[self textView1] text]` then all you need do is pass it to an instance of `NSURL *` and check using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:]` that you can open the URL. Once this has been checked and if true you can then open it using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:]`. Also ensure that all your `IBOutlets` are correctly linked otherwise it will not do anything.

**SozdikViewController.h**

```
// Start of interface file
@interface SozdikViewController : UIViewController

// Property declarations
// Note the lower cases at the beginning of the property variable names
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textView1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonAsk; 

// Method declarations
- (IBAction)ask;

@end
// end of interface file
```

**SozdikViewController.m**

```
// Start of implementation file
#import "SozdikViewController.h"

// You are clearly not using the class extention so why is it there
// Removed it as it is pointless being there if you aren't using it

@implementation SozdikViewController

// Synthesize is done for you automatically

- (IBAction)ask
{
    // We are going to do it like everyone says but add a few checks in
    // First lets check to make sure that the textView1s text isn't nil or an empty string
    if([[self textView1] text] != nil && ![[[self textView1] text] isEqualToString:@""]) {
        // Construct the URL with the word that has been passed in
        NSURL *urlString = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.audaru.kz/?product=SoylemMT&word=%@", [[self textView1] text]]];
        // Next check to make sure that the URL can actually be opened
        // otherwise forget about it as it would be pointless.
        if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:urlString]) {
            // We can open it so lets open it
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:urlString];
        } else {
            // else do something to tell the use it can't be done.
        }
    }
}

@end
// end of implementation file
```